# When is a linear program feasible but not optimal?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

> Let be the following program
>   $$\begin{array}{rrcr@{\qquad}l}
> \text{max:} &4x_1 &+& 5x_2 &\\
> \text{subject to:} &2x_1 &+& x_2 &\le 8\\
> &x_1 &+& 2x_2 &\le 7\\
> & & &x_2&\le 3\\
> \forall i,x_i\ge 0
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> with $x_1\prime=1$ and $x_2\prime = 3$ is it feasible? Optimal?

I first tried to see if it satisfied complementary slackness theorem
$$
\begin{array}
& 2*1 &+&  3 &= 5 &\le 8&(\Rightarrow y_1 = 0)\\
1 &+& 2*3 &= 7\\ 
& & 3 &= 3
\end{array}
$$
Therefore I think it is feasible.

Yet when providing its dual. I find out that $y_2 = 4$ and $y_3 = -3$... As far as the last one is $<0$ does it mean it **is feasible and not optimal?**

Comment: If the LP is unbounded, then it is feasible, but there is no optimum.

Comment: Testing for feasibility does _not_ require checking complementary slackness. It only requires checking that the primal constraints are satisfied. And indeed, all inequalities are satisfied. It is only when checking _optimality_ that you might consider complementary slackness.

Comment: So yes: if $y_2=4$ and $y_3=-3$ are what is naturally obtained for the dual here, then this can't be an optimal point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is $x=(1,3)$ feasible: yes, the constraints are satisfied.

Is $x=(1,3)$ optimal? Consider complementary slackness:

$\begin{align}
y_1(2 x_1 + x_2 - 8) = 0 \\
y_2(x_1 + 2 x_2 - 7) = 0 \\
y_3(x_2 - 3) = 0 \\
x_1(2y_1 + y_2-4) = 0 \\
x_2(y_1 + 2y_2 + y_3-5) = 0
\end{align}$

The first two equalities yield $y_1=y_2=0$, but this violates the fourth equality. Since no $y \geq 0$ can be found that satisfies complementary slackness, $x$ is not optimal.